# Select teachers for course in edit view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Some of my models:

```
class Provider < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :courses, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :teachers, dependent: :destroy

end

class Course < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :teachers, through: :staff_profiles
    has_many :staff_profiles, dependent: :destroy

    belongs_to :provider
    belongs_to :staff_profile

end

class Teacher < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :courses, through: :staff_profiles
    has_many :staff_profiles, dependent: :destroy
    belongs_to :provider

end
```

In the course edit view I want to have all provider's teachers to let the user select which teachers will belong to the course.

What would be the **simplest** way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do this:

```
# app/controller/courses_controller.rb
def edit
  @course = Course.find(params[:id]) # find the course here
  @provider_teachers = @course.provider.teachers
end
```

Also, add `belongs_to :provider` association in your `Teacher` model and the corresponding foreign key (`provider_id`) in the `teachers` table.

Comment: What is challenging to me is to present it on the view and let the user pick which teachers belong to  the course. I thought of doing it with check boxes and process the result in the controller, but I wonder if there is an easier way.